# Filter List as per Date in Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-button

Displaying a list from API. I want to show list based on date. There are three buttons in my view : Previous Day, Last Three Days, and a button providing calendar to chose dates.(Havent implemented the third button yet). Here is the view:

```
struct TrackSampleOptions: View {    
@StateObject var trackViewModel = TrackViewModel()

var body: some View {        
    NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: YdaySample(),isActive: 
                                 $trackViewModel.navigate,
                 label:{ Button(action: {
                    trackViewModel.searchToday = "One"
                                trackViewModel.getTrack()                        
                                },
                     label:{ Text("Previous Day")
                                }).buttonStyle(trackButton())
                        
                           })  .navigationTitle("Track Options")
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                
        NavigationLink(destination: YdaySample(),isActive: 
                  $trackViewModel.navigate,
        label:{Button(action: {
                    trackViewModel.searchToday = "Two"
                    trackViewModel.getTrack()
                              },
                     label:{
                                Text("Last Three Days")
                                }).buttonStyle(trackButton())
                        
            })  .navigationTitle("Track Options")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
             }
             }
         }
         }
```

Here is the viewModel:

```
class TrackViewModel : ObservableObject
      {
            @Published var trackReport = [TrackResponse]()
            @Published var navigate:Bool = false
            @Published var searchToday: String = ""
            @Published var centerID: String = String()
            @Published var errorMessage:String = String()
            private let trackResource = TrackResource()
  func getTrack()
       {
        var startDate:String = String()
        var endDate:String = String()
        var searchText:String = String()
    
    if(searchToday == "One")
    {
        let today:Date = Date()
        var dayafter:Date = Date()
        dayafter = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, 
         to: Date())!

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let start = formatter.string(from: dayafter)

        startDate = start + " 00:00:00"

        let endFormatter = DateFormatter()
        endFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        
        endDate = endFormatter.string(from: today)
        searchText = ""
   }
    else if (searchToday == "Two")
    {
        let today:Date = Date()
        var dayafter:Date = Date()
        dayafter = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -3, 
        to: Date())!

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let start = formatter.string(from: dayafter)

        startDate = start + " 00:00:00"

        let endFormatter = DateFormatter()
        endFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        
        endDate = endFormatter.string(from: today)
        searchText = ""
    }
    centerID = "668"
    
    let trackRequest = TrackRequest(CenterId:centerID, 
    SearchText:searchText, StartDate:startDate, EndDate:endDate)
    trackResource.track(trackRequest: trackRequest)
    {
        response in
        if(response?.success==true)
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigate = true
                self.trackReport = response?.trackResponse ?? []
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorMessage = response?.message ?? "No Data"
             
                       }
                    }
               }
          }
```

TrackResource is a struct which contains the URL Request code. Four params are passed into the POST URLRequest body - CenterId(for testing i hardcoded the value it will be returned from userdefaults), SearchText(which is empty in case of these two buttons will be used in another module), StartDate and EndDate. Now code is running list is loaded into the following YdaySample struct successfully.

```
import SwiftUI

 struct YdaySample: View {

      @StateObject var tracking = TrackViewModel()

         var body: some View {
 
          NavigationView{
                               List{
                              ForEach(tracking.trackReport)
                             {
                              truck in
                               NavigationLink(destination: 
                               TrackDetail(track:truck))
                            {
                                YdayRow(truck: truck)
                            }
                           }
                 }.onAppear
               {
                      tracking.getTrack()
                       }
                 }
            }
       }
```

TrackDetail is a struct for detail view and YdayRow is for row of list. List is loading.

However, **entire list is loading completely instead of date criteria**. In debug, start and end date are showing correctly. **Simply, when i click previous Day, list should only show records between yesterday and current time.** **IMO, the issue is sending searchToday variable to view model by click of button.** I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your issue because we can't debug your code for you, what has YdaySample to do with this for instance, is a request even sent to the server, do you get a response, your use of the searchText variable looks strange etc etc?

Comment: not clear to me what the question is. Could you explain what the question is, and what is not working.

Comment: there are three buttons in a view...Previous Day, Last Three Days, Select Date. On clicking any button list is loaded based on date range....for Previous Day the date range is yday to todays's current time on which button is clicked(I have written in q this). Eg if I click Previous Day button date range should be startDate = "2022-04-16 00:00:00" to endDate = "2022-04-17 19:23:15" there are two more params centerID and searchText the request is a post request all four are sent in form data format..(1/n)

Comment: I am trying to pass trackViewModel.searchToday = "One" from struct TrackSampleOptions to TrackViewModel so that on basis of this value in viewmodel, dates can be set. In Last Three Days button this value is set to "Two"....what is happening is full list is loading in first two cases (havent written for select date button till now)

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand what the question is and what the problem you are having.

"...list is loaded...", what list, I don't see any list or any loading in your code.

"Filter List as per Date in Swiftui", you don't show any code that does any filtering.

"...List is loading completely in YdaySample() view and in console it is showing "no date"..."
What are you talking about here.

Comment: OK rephrasing and adding more code in the Question

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your view model in YdaySample rather than using the existing one from the calling view which means that any values it contains will be lost. You should pass the view model from one view to the other or pass the search type to the second view and only use the view model there.

Comment: thank @JoakimDanielson worked on your suggestion, I resolved the issue now it is working as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add to pass view data: YdaySample(tracking: trackViewModel)